# WIX: How to get value of selected feature of selectiontree to display on summary page

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.7, wix3.8

I want to write summary page with selected feature and installation location. I am using ADDLOCAL to display selected feature but it will work if I use command line with addlocal to select the feature but if I use UI then it does not display selected feature.

```
<Control Id="InstalledFeaturesText" Type="Text" X="25" Y="215" Height="10" Width="100" Text="[ADDLOCAL]"/>
```

even I tried

```
<SetProperty Id="FEATURELIST" Value="[ADDLOCAL]" After="CostFinalize"/>
<Control Id="InstalledFeaturesText" Type="Text" X="25" Y="215" Height="10" Width="100" Text="[FEATURELIST]"/>
```

Is there any other way to do that ?
Please help me.

Comment: We don't know where your dialog is being displayed, that may be an issue. At the very end of the install? Somewhere in the beginning UI sequence? I'm a bit curious as to why you don't just use ADDLOCAL - I see no reason to capture it at some point in the UI and save it in another property.

Comment: I want to use dialogue just after feature page on place of verifyreadydlg that is on page that has install button. If I use ADDLOCAL through command line then It is displaying the selected feature but if use UI then It is not showing selected feature.